# Insert query table lock

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a table in the Postgresql database. I try to insert a row into the table through java code and it takes 23 milliseconds. when I execute the same code 1000 times through multithreading where maximum thread count is 300 at any point of time, the resultant output time is more or less same as 1000 times of one query execution time. I have checked the code.there is no locks acquired on the java side.is there any internal locks acquired on the database level

Comment: Can you show me your insert statement? Does it use a sequence for the primary key, or is it querying the table as well. You should be able to insert multiple rows in parallel. Additionally, if you have all the row data at once, there's a way to bulk insert that's much faster.  Last optional quesiton: Are you using a connection pooler and multiple connections? Java will require multiple connections to perform multiple tasks at once.

Comment: I am having this issue as well, 2022 but using python inserting to RDS PSQL with sqlalchemy. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Yes,as postgres is ACID(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) complaint.  Update, Insert and Delete set a lock on the table when a transaction is in progress. I have attached link to the Postgres documentation is attached.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

hope this helps

Comment: Actually, this is not a description of the process. Postgres does contain a lock, but only for the row being inserted (or rows being read), so multiple inserts can happen concurrently as long as they have different primary keys.

Comment: How do unique indexes get checked then? I have a transaction with an insert in it, and a long delay (while an API runs)... originally I had the code where the commit doesn't happen until the very end, but I wound up having to commit it prior to the API running, then delete the record if the API fails... any workarounds?